# Is all auto increment must be primary key? If yes how to I change all primary keys with auto_increment in imported database in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

When I import SQL file into a database that has 1GB. I have tried

```
shell_exce('mysql -uusername -ppassword database_name < sqlfiel.sql')
```

But it was not set primary keys as auto_increment. So that I have

> "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

This error when I insert data into DB.

How to set need primary key column as auto_increment?

Comment: "Is all auto increment must be primary key?" -- In MySQL, yes. Other databases offer different options.

Comment: But you shall define (as per your requirement) some other primary key and let id as it is. But no point in keeping an id with auto_increment when you bulk import data into the table with wrong values for id !!!

Comment: Actually it is not - an example if you set primary key to be a string. The primary key has to be unique, that’s the only requirement, and hence why you receive the error.

Comment: More chances that your source data has the id column as 0 for several rows. While importing, it is generating error

Comment: @TheImpaler - Thanks for your information. Some of the auto_increment filed get not set while I imported 1GB of MySQL file or Magento project. Do you know any option to set all primary keys as auto_increment in MySQL?

Comment: @NatarajanNNapoleon - I accept your  answer but In my case, all primary keys are int only (I am not sure but its Magento project, am not familiar with Magento )

Comment: Both my previous comments are valid still. Being key int auto_increment, if you import bulk data (to all the columns of the table) it will generate error and beyond the error, it is better not to import data for auto_increment column. Please look for duplicate values in your bulk data for that key column.

Comment: @NatarajanNNapoleon -  Thank you for your information

Comment: For me that kind of error usually happens when you try to import VARCHAR into INT field: strings are converted to int's and becomes 0, hence `Duplicate entry '0'`